# Zeros of holomorphic one-forms on Riemann surface

Tags: holomorphic-symplectic

Is it true that for any point on any compact Riemann surface there exists a global holomorphic one-form, which does NOT have a zero at that point.

Comment: Recently it has been proven by Schnell, that  If $X$ is a projective manifold of general type, then every holomorphic one-form on $X$ vanishes at some point

Comment: For a compact Riemann surface $S$, genus$ g(S)=1$ iff $S$ admit a complex holomorphic one form without zero iff $S$ admit a holomorphic tangent vector field without zero

Comment: Additional note: The space of holomorphic one-forms on a torus $\mathbb C/Λ$ has complex dimension 1. If $\omega$ is a meromorphic differential on a Riemann surface $S$  of genus $g$ then the number
of zeros of $ω$ minus the number of poles, counted with multiplicity is $2g − 2$,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On $\mathbb P^1$, there is no non zero holomorphic $1$-form, on any elliptic curves, the holomorphic forms are "constant" (the canonical bundle is trivial), so never vanish if they are not identically zero.

As for the other surfaces, namely if $g(X) \geqslant 2$, then  $|K_X|$ has no base point (cf Hartshorne, IV, lemma 5.1), which amouts to saying that for all point $x\in X$, there exists a holomorphic form non-vanishing at $x$.

Moreover, if $X$ has genus $g\geqslant 2$ as previously and $X$ is not hyperelliptic, then $K_X$ is very ample (cf Hartshorne, IV, proposition 5.2), which means that the linear system given by the (global) holomorphic $1$-forms induces an embedding into $\mathbb P H^0(X, K_X)^* \simeq \mathbb P^{g-1}$.

Comment: Proposition 2.1.https://people.ucsc.edu/~rmont/classes/RiemSurfaces/2013/lectures/CountingZerosPoles_RiemRoch.pdf